# Credit memo's total must be positive

Tags: magento-1, creditmemo

At first, this has been [asked before](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63014/create-credit-memo-for-zero-product-value). But no one has answered yet.

My Sales rep sometime create orders with items having `0 cost`. And the problem is now, when customer return those items, magento doesn't allow us to create **Credit Memo**.

It throw error message:

> Credit memo's total must be positive.

I can see this function is responsible for this:

```
            if (($creditmemo->getGrandTotal() <=0) && (!$creditmemo->getAllowZeroGrandTotal())) {
                 Mage::throwException(
                    $this->__('Credit Memo total must be positive.')
                 );
             }
```

I can surely remove this condition from `Save Credit Memo` function.

But **I want to know if it will trigger some other issue? Why magento has this condition in first place?**

Answer (score 1):

You can observe `adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_register_before`

And then change the value

```
public function adminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoRegisterBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $oEvent)
    {
        $oCreditMemo = $oEvent->getCreditmemo();
        if ($oCreditMemo && ($oCreditMemo instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo)){
            /**
             * Allow credit memo with zero amount
             */
            $oCreditMemo->setAllowZeroGrandTotal(true);
        }
    }
```